# How to make daisyui preserve tailwind.config theme?

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

I know that daisyui themes uses `@apply text-sm` for `.btn` and `.input` as default behavior.

But when configure it in `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        sm: '2rem',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('daisyui')],
};
```

It doesn't affect on a result.

Possible way to override styles through css

```css
[data-theme='light'] .btn {
  @apply text-sm;
}
```

But we should tweak all changed default styles.

I wonder is there a way to make daisyui plugin preserve user `tailwind.config.js` theme?

sandbox - https://stackblitz.com/edit/daisyui-vue-vite-htu1is?file=tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure from your `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  //...

  // add daisyUI plugin
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],

  // daisyUI config (optional)
  daisyui: {
    styled: true,
    themes: true,
    base: true,
    utils: true,
    logs: true,
    rtl: false,
    prefix: "",
    darkTheme: "dark",
  },
}
```

**styled means** - if it's true, components will have colors and style so you won't need to design anything. If it's false, components will have no color and no visual style so you can design your own style on a basic skeleton.

Find more [here](https://daisyui.com/docs/config/)

Comment: additionally worth mentioning: no prefix for daisy means same prefix as tailwind, so if tailwind has "tw-" prefix, and daisy "" then both get "tw-" which is handy. but you can also separate them.

Comment: another thing to consider is using "unocss" which is the successor of windicss which is the successor of tailwind afaik